# AG-Grid: What is the property for header group renderer

Tags: ag-grid

I can target almost all the header cells with `headerCellRenderer`, however when in a group the ones with red arrows are ignored:

[image: Cell Renderer not affecting header group cells]

I've tried these but nothing works:

```
headerGroupRenderer: () => '0',
headerGroupCellRenderer: () => '1',
groupHeaderCellRenderer: () => '2',
groupHeaderRenderer: () => '3',
```

What's the correct property to target those cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`headerGroupComponent`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/) ...perhaps?

Comment: Thanks you're right, however I then have to provide a whole new inner template. I worry that if I copy some template it could easily get out of date. Wish there was a simpler way, or a way to inherit the template and just decorate it with a class! In general I wish it was easier just to add a class (and also other attributes) to headers without having to re-write templates.